What to do when users refuse to abide by community standards?
I recently came across a question where someone had put his question in the title but not in the body, which under normal circumstances is easily rectifiable, except his question was edited multiple times to include the problem in the body and multiple times he re-edited his question to remove the question from the body, claiming that having the question in both the title and the question is redundant.  To further compound the matter, he went back and re-edited every question he had ever asked to remove the question from the body and just have it in the title.  He hadn't asked many questions, so this particular case isn't a large issue, but it speaks to a more general question.
What should be done when users are openly hostile to community standards like this?

Do you know whether that user is aware of the site expectation that the question should be in the body of the question?

@dan Yes, when the first person to edit his post to add the question to the body, they gave a link to the post on asking a good question, said explicitly that the question had to be in the body, and in follow-up comments discussing his re-edit, he said it was a bad rule that he refused to follow.

Flag one of the questions for moderator attention, including the details you've given here.

Is this the question?

@ТymaGaidash Yes.

Seems like the moderator flag worked. User is suspended for 7 days. And a moderator has reverted the edits. But the questions are all closed or deleted anyway.

Let me remark that the question in the title is much more general than what is being asked here. I would say about 80% of users don't care about the guideline that duplicates as well as poor quality questions should not be answered (which also includes of course to search for duplicates before answering - otherwise you don't know). And this behavior is mostly tolerated.

@MartinBrandenburg I would argue that there is a difference between not abiding by community standards and actively refusing to follow them.  There is a difference between saying "I can't be bothered to put in the effort to do that" and "I stand firmly opposed to anybody who does that."
